# Prove: $\forall X \in \mathscr{I}(r)(\exists Y \subseteq X(r \in Y \wedge \forall z \in Y(Y \in \mathscr{I}(z))))$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

In the book I am reading the following

**Prop. 1**: let be $(A,B)$ a topological space, $r \in A$, and $\mathscr{I}(r):=\text{family of neighbourhoods of }r$, then $$\forall X \in \mathscr{I}(r)(\exists Y \subseteq X(r \in Y \wedge \forall z \in Y(Y \in  \mathscr{I}(z))))$$

In my studies I use the following definition of neighbourhood of $r$

**Def. 1**: let be $(A,B)$ a topological space, $r \in A$, and $T \subseteq A$, $T$ is neighbourhood of $r$ if $$\exists Z \in B(r \in Z \subseteq T)$$

The proof of **Prop. 1** is:

**Proof.**: by hypothesis $X \in \mathscr{I}(r)$ then $\exists Z \in B(r \in Z \subseteq X)$, if $Z \in B $ then $ Z \subseteq A$, let be $z \in Z$ I have $Z \in \mathscr{I}(z)$ because $\exists R \in B (z \in R \subseteq Z)$ and it is $Z$ in fact by hypothesis I have $B \ni Z \wedge Z \subseteq A \wedge z \in Z$... therefore the **Prop. 1** is true!

Is it correct? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed. **Prop. 1** says that every neighbourhood $X$ of a point $r$ contains a special neighbourhood $Y$ that is a neighbourhood of *all* of its points.

And an open set can be characterised (using your **Def. 1**) as a set that is a neighbourhood of all of its points. So we just use that a set is a neighbourhood of $r$ means that it contains an open neighbourhood of $r$, and this open neighbourhood is as required.

Comment: @ГарнакОлэговытц Yes, it is. It's written down quite formally, so I wanted to formulate it in a more loose manner.

Comment: thanks.. :), when You wrote "$r$ contains a special neighbourhood $Y$ that is a neighbourhood of all of its points", Is also "special neighbourhood $Y$" of $r$?

Comment: @ГарнакОлэговытц Yes, the $Y$ is the neighbourhood of $r$ that is a neighbourhood of all of its points (which is what the logical formula says, right?).

Comment: true, of course..sorry I read it wrong! Thanks soo much! :)